# Center Counter Bootstrap Modal

Tags: html, css, counter

I have a counter with increase decrease button. It's inside a model-content, but I can't center it in the middle of the modal. Can you help me?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkoMZ.png

```
    <div class="input-group" style="width:25%;">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <span class="btn btn-white btn-minuse" type="button">-</span>
        </span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control text-center height-25" value=0 >
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <span class="btn btn-red btn-pluss" type="button">+</span>
        </span>
    </div>
```

Comment: like center it horizontally? or vertically.? also all you are showing is a div. Can you share your model code with the CSS so we can help more?

Comment: the css, is a standard import of boostrap.css file . I like orizontally

Comment: i post image, how is it now

Comment: Still there some custom CSS you may have applied. also having the HTML code will help us a lot. Anyway check my answer and let me know if that helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To center it you should use `margin: 0 auto`. And that will solve your problem

```html
<div class="input-group" style="width:25%; margin: 0 auto;">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
            <span class="btn btn-white btn-minuse" type="button">-</span>
  </span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control text-center height-25" value=0>
  <span class="input-group-btn">
            <span class="btn btn-red btn-pluss" type="button">+</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Also, avoid using Inline CSS styles. If that didn't help please let me know.

Comment: and another question, how can i give a space from text to input, <br> don't work

Comment: so you want to add space between your text and input group?

Comment: yes, i want it ! i'm not really good on front-development

Comment: simply since you are using bootstrap you can add `mt-*` to your `input-group` div and it will add some space. you can use `mt-3` or `mt-2` or `mt-1` 4 and 5 are also available to use. And that will just add `margin top `and you will get space.